# React conditional rendering of JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Does the following style of conditional rendering look fine or can this be improved further ?

```
<ColumnLayout>
    {
        (stateVar1 === 'AR') && (
            <div>
                if (stateVar2 === '') {
                    <div>
                        <Button id="btn1">Btn1</Button> 
                        <Button id="btn2">Btn2</Button> 
                    </div>
                }
                if (stateVar2 === 'AP') {   
                    <div>
                        <Button id="btn3">Btn3</Button> 
                        <Button id="btn4">Btn4</Button> 
                    </div>
                }   
            </div>
        )
    }
</ColumnLayout>
```

Comment: Depends. Can stateVar2 have only those two values once stateVar1 === 'AR'

Answer (score 0):

```
<ColumnLayout>
    {
        (stateVar1 === 'AR') && (
            <div>
                { (stateVar2 === '') &&
                    <div>
                        <Button id="btn1">Btn1</Button> 
                        <Button id="btn2">Btn2</Button> 
                    </div>
                }
                { (stateVar2 === 'AP')  &&    
                    <div>
                        <Button id="btn3">Btn3</Button> 
                        <Button id="btn4">Btn4</Button> 
                    </div>
                }   
            </div>
        )
    }
</ColumnLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks...just one last question...if i want to check for null or empty value...can I do this
(stateVar2 === '' || staveVar2 === null)

Comment: you can just check with (!stateVar2) ; this returns true for `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""` so on.